# PhoneGap localStorage taking too long to access data

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, local-storage

I have saved long string in localMemory named `UserContacts`, but it takes very long to access the data, here is the code that I am using:

```
var $Contacts = $('#Contacts');
        var htmltext = window.localStorage.getItem("UserContacts");
        $(htmltext).appendTo($Contacts);
        $Contacts.listview("refresh").listview();
```

Any ideas how to improve performance for this?

P.S. I am developing application for android and using PhoneGap.

 Thank you.

Comment: if this is a simple html content, then you can save it in another html file and can load using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instread of storing html in localstorage you should save only data and then create your html using javascript, see below code

```
var data = window.localStorage.getItem("UserContacts");
var len = data.length;
var html = "";
for(var i=0; i< len;i++) {
html += $("<li/>").text(data[i]);
}   

$("ul#yourId").append(html)
```